# (C++)Code::Blocks possible wrong setup for Qt4

Tags: c++, qt4, codeblocks

OS : windows xp  SP2 ,
compiler : Code::Blocks ver. 10.05 ,
Qt 4.6

I recently started to learn Qt. At first all went well with simple tut examples.
I soon came across an example that can not compile and and realized that something is  wrong.

Here is the code :

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDesktopWidget>


class Communicate : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    Communicate(QWidget *parent = 0);

  private slots:
    void OnPlus();
    void OnMinus();

  private:
    QLabel *label;

};


 void center(QWidget *widget, int w, int h)
{
  int x, y;
  int screenWidth;
  int screenHeight;

  QDesktopWidget *desktop = QApplication::desktop();

  screenWidth = desktop->width();
  screenHeight = desktop->height();

  x = (screenWidth - w) / 2;
  y = (screenHeight - h) / 2;

  widget->move( x, y );
}


Communicate::Communicate(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
  int WIDTH = 350;
  int HEIGHT = 190;

  resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

  QPushButton *plus = new QPushButton("+", this);
  plus->setGeometry(50, 40, 75, 30);

  QPushButton *minus = new QPushButton("-", this);
  minus->setGeometry(50, 100, 75, 30);

  label = new QLabel("0", this);
  label->setGeometry(190, 80, 20, 30);

  connect(plus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnPlus()));
  connect(minus, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(OnMinus()));


  center(this, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

}

void Communicate::OnPlus()
{
  int val = label->text().toInt();
  val++;
  label->setText(QString::number(val));
}

void Communicate::OnMinus()
{
  int val = label->text().toInt();
  val--;
  label->setText(QString::number(val));
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Communicate window;

  window.setWindowTitle("Communicate");
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

When I try to open it, I get this message:

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `vtable for Communicate'|

obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp|| more undefined references to `vtable for Communicate' follow|

||=== Build finished: 6 errors, 0 warnings ===|

I was looking for a solution to the code:: blocks forum and learned that there should be Qt plugin installed.

So , I install QtWorkbench 0.6.0 alpha -> qt plugin but nothing has changed.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Can you compile a Qt application at all? Like if you just instantiated a QWidget in main and showed it?

Comment: Yes, I can compile a Qt application.
There is a default example when i start new Qt4 project and all goes well.

Comment: Do you #include "Communication.h" in main.cpp?

Comment: No , I done just like i posted.

Answer (score 2):

Did you moc this file and include the moc output to get compiled?

Whenever you use the Q_OBJECT macro, you must use Qt's moc command on that file to generate a new cpp file which should also be included in the files to be compiled with your project.  In addition, I believe that you can only moc a header file, so you will have to move your class definition to a separate file and moc that file.

I don't know how it works for your IDE, but on the command line you would call something like

```
<QT4 directory>\bin\moc.exe myfile.h -o moc_myfile.cpp
```

Then include the file moc_myfile.cpp in the project as well.

In some IDEs that is what the Qt plugin does for you; It automates all those steps or uses qmake which does not require explicit moc'ing.  In Visual Studio I just use Custom Build Steps.

Comment: No and I dont now how to do that!

Comment: I hope that the Qt plugin does this thing but I am not sure.

Comment: Look in the settings for the QtWorkbench.  I think it has a setting for the moc directory; Something like "mocs".  Then look in your project folder to see if there is a directory there and if there are any files in it.

Comment: Further reading of the Qt documentation leaves me to believe that you cannot moc a cpp file, only a header file.  Also I believe that the QtWorkbench uses qmake which does not require explicit moc'ing.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I just looked.There is no settings for plugin QtWorkbench. When I open MANAGE PLUGINS, it just gives me options : enable plugin , disable , install new and uninstall. It seems to me that i can not  do further adjustment.

Comment: Hmmm. I was looking at http://code.google.com/p/qtworkbench/wiki/BuildingQtProjects and that's why I thought there was a setting.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I opened the options in the project and there is QtWorkbench settings. SORRY , will try now experiment with that

Comment: First, try moving the class definition to a separate header file.

Comment: I 'm the author of QtWorkbench and I have stopped supporting it some  time ago. I 'm pretty sure it's outdated by now. I really think that new Qt users should go with QtCreator the "official" Qt IDE to get the best support out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the call to center() in the Communication constructor. I believe this might be causing your errors.

Comment: I have done so but there is no solution.

//center(this, WIDTH, HEIGHT);  gives the same result.

The other examples do not work and it seems to me that the thing is in the settings for qt project in code::blocks.